# Redmine (ruby on rails app) apache config problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, redmine

I've got the following problem. I wanted to use Redmine for project management and have installed Ruby on Rails on my CentOS 5.5 VPS. The VPS is running Virtualmin to host multiple websites. 
So far so good. Now I came to the step to configure apache. I want redmine to show up under redmine.mydomain.com and added the following to my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost MYIP:80>
ServerName redmine.MYDOMAIN.com
DocumentRoot /home/redmine/
<Directory /home/redmine/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /redmine
</VirtualHost>
```

In the LoadModules section I have added:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

I made a symlink from /home/redmine to /opt/redmine/public (the public directory of the redmine app)

Now what happens is that when calling http://redmine.mydomain.com/ I will get a directory listing of the files /opt/redmine/public instead of the redmine application coming up.

If I change the RailsBaseURI to /, then it will show me a fancy passenger error screen telling 'Ruby on Rails application could not be started', which probably makes sense since it shows Application root: /home, which is one level above the symlink to the application public location.

I am quite lost, read many howtos but I new to both redmine installation and RoR. Hope someone can guide me how to debug this.

Comment: What I now did was changing the symlinks for the real directories. Still some version errors, but I feel that I am getting somewhere.

Comment: This should probably be moved to Server Fault.

Comment: I got it up and running now. I used the following Apache config where I use the real path instead of symbolic links.
`<VirtualHost myip:80>
ServerName redmine.host.nl
DocumentRoot /opt/redmine/public
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/redmine_error_log
<Directory /opt/redmine/public>
allow from all
Options -MultiViews        
</Directory>
RailsEnv production
# RailsBaseURI /redmine
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to deploy to a sub-URI, using the Passenger terminology.

See the instructions for this at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Your configuration is a bit different. In particular it looks like you need to turn MultiViews off for the /redmine directory.

Comment: Can I consider http://redmine.domain.com/ as a sub-URI? I don't really want to access it like: http://redmine.domain.com/redmine.

Comment: That's a hostname, not a sub-URI. You'll need to remove the RailsBaseURI setting, which is for sub-URIs.

Answer (score 0):

I use Redmine on a CentOS 5 machine at work.  I have to admit that I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, so I don't know how to fix it, but what I do is:

1. Run a [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) instance of the server (with something like `script/server thin -e production`).
2. Have [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) reverse-proxy requests to it.  You should be able to do this with Apache, too.

An advantage to this is that Redmine and the web server are separate - if I can access Redmine on port 3000 but not where I want it, then Redmine's working and I just have to figure out why Cherokee's not proxying correctly.